# No response at all from JQuery request to XML formatted API, even using alert() as debug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm trying to make a request to Google Places API to return all the "rating" values from the script and store them in an Array so I can calculate the average. The only problem is the button I'm using to call the method to do this does nothing when pressed, leading me to believe that something is wrong with my JQuery ajax call. Any ideas?

```
  function getCafe(){

       // Latitude and longitude variables provided by the user from a searched location
       $('.search_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
       $('.search_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());

       var Lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
       var Long = marker.getPosition().lng();
       var cafeRatings = [];
       var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=" + Lat + "," + Long + "&amp;radius=500&amp;type=restaurant&amp;keyword=cruise&amp;key="MY_API_KEY";


       $(document).ready(function(){
           $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "xml",
            url: url,
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('results').each(function(){
                    $(this).find("rating").each(function(){
                        var rating = $(this).text();
                        cafeRatings.push(rating);
                    });
                });
                alert(cafeRatings.join("\n"));
            }
           });
          });
    }
```

The XML Script looks like this

```
<PlaceSearchResponse>
<status>OK</status>


 <result>
         <name>Sydney Showboats</name>
         <vicinity>32 The Promenade, Sydney</vicinity>
         <type>travel_agency</type>
         <type>restaurant</type>
         <type>food</type>
         <type>point_of_interest</type>
         <type>establishment</type>
    <geometry>
        <location>
        <lat>-33.8675570</lat>
        <lng>151.2015270</lng>
        </location>
          <viewport>
           <southwest>
             <lat>-33.8689120</lat>
             <lng>151.2001126</lng>
           </southwest>
           <northeast>
             <lat>-33.8662141</lat>
             <lng>151.2028105</lng>
           </northeast>
          </viewport>
    </geometry>
    <rating>3.8</rating> <------ This is the element im trying to ad to the array
    <icon>
    https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png
    </icon>
    <reference>
    CmRSAAAALItuCtuLapozzsjq3dmKqj7NDik149XsgUwHD3ob5AWfHYlZtykuJbQa0cq0GMqX8dRgucTCmitnXgV-ekE3GfV7910rzHhx3ZuadVYNuWMzLDVZDCj2G1yiBw8r_hhgEhCPDXsniaZ2ZrkvYyXFfmQrGhSzdmkAEz4stXNx2qFe-GqAlldzgw
    </reference>
    <id>ce4ffe228ab7ad49bb050defe68b3d28cc879c4a</id>
    <opening_hours>
    <open_now>false</open_now>
    </opening_hours>
    <photo>
    <photo_reference>
    CmRaAAAAh4dP9hsZ_6515QNxouVnuYFYKemmf8BE01rcaOvkFlILQiwGNe_OAX0ikmobMmWZJvyjsFEsn7j1TFhauHSrek8nY5GsW24_6nwJsqEwHTUC10SL5gQITHhkdam50G1PEhCP-C7Of2mkjqJCTYFeYGWuGhQjVoWASHiGSp3WHm26Bh2sYOglZw
    </photo_reference>
    <width>2048</width>
    <height>1152</height>
    <html_attribution>
    <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107415973755376511005/photos">Sydney Showboats</a>
    </html_attribution>
    </photo>
    <place_id>ChIJjRuIiTiuEmsRCHhYnrWiSok</place_id>
    <scope>GOOGLE</scope>
    </result>
........
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

But no error's are shown either in the browser or in my eclipse error log? Is this method of querying a XML API correct?

Comment: Use the console to debug the request. If there's no `success` response it's likely there's an error HTTP status coming back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You have two main problems

- Your URL has `&amp;` HTML entity, so you need to remove that and concatenate your params with `&` only.
- For sure, the problem is [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to let a user agent gain permission to access selected resources from a server on a different origin (domain) than the site currently in use. A user agent makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource from a different domain, protocol, or port than the one from which the current document originated.

Follow this [resource](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) from Google places.

This code snippet has the URL with the `&` and I've added the `error` function to inspect the error response.

```js
function getCafe() {

  // Latitude and longitude variables provided by the user from a searched location
  //$('.search_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
  //$('.search_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());

  var Lat = 5;
  var Long = 5;
  var cafeRatings = [];
  var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=" + Lat + "," + Long + "&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=API_KEY";


  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "xml",
      url: url,
      success: function(xml) {
        console.log(xml)
        $(xml).find('results').each(function() {
          $(this).find("rating").each(function() {
            var rating = $(this).text();
            cafeRatings.push(rating);
          });
        });
        alert(cafeRatings.join("\n"));
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  });
}

getCafe();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Eleazar, thanks for the reply. I was previously looking into this and by removing the amp; from the url the program immediately prompts a `SAXParseException` claiming that `The reference to entity "radius" must end with the ';' delimiter.`

Comment: I did some research on what your answer and your right I think it is an issue with CORS, however, this seems to contradict with exceptions in Eclipse would you have any idea on this? I go into this issue more in depth  in another question I asked (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503813/is-there-a-way-to-bypass-chrome-security-and-eclipse-saxparseexception-contradic)