# What can I do when Eclipse can't read '&' and Browser can't read '&amp;' when running a JQuery to a Google API via URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, eclipse, google-chrome

I'm attempting to use a jquery to access data from Google Places API but it seems that Google Chrome and Eclipse are contradicting each other. I originally tried to parse the API in XML format, but was met with the following error in Chrome's developer tools console when I tried to run the query:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:8080/ No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Therefore I changed the URL to access the JSON format and changed the data type in the ajax request to `datatype: jsonp` as a way to overcome the XMLHttpRequest same domain policy. As a result, the URL cannot contain `&amp;` to avoid Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) and ensure the URL is properly formatted. However, the issue now is that I'm getting a SAXParseException in my Eclipse error console that says `The reference to entity "radius" must end with the ';' delimiter` for which the only fix is to replace `&` with `&amp;`. To eliminate all possibilities I then included `&amp;` in the URL again but this prompts `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected (the API URL included below) token :` in Chrome's developer tools console which is a reference to the `&amp;` in the URL. Thus bringing me back to square one. Is there a fix for this?

My Ajax JQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.search_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
           $('.search_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());

           var Lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
           console.log(Lat);
           var Long = marker.getPosition().lng();
           console.log(Long);
           var cafeRatings = [];
           var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + Lat + "," + Long + "&amp;radius=500&amp;type=restaurant&amp;keyword=cruise&amp;key=MY_API_KEY";

           $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: url,
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('results').each(function(){
                    $(this).find("rating").each(function(){
                        var rating = $(this).text();
                        cafeRatings.push(rating);
                    });
                });
                alert(cafeRatings.join("\n"));
            }
           });
          });
```

The API URL I'm trying to access (`&amp` included)

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + Lat + "," + Long + "&amp;radius=500&amp;type=restaurant&amp;keyword=cruise&amp;key=MY_API_KEY";
```

Comment: did you enable javascript support for your project? if not enable it. https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/enabling_javascript_support_in_php_projects.htm and then just use an &. Only use &amp; in an attribute `<button onclick="window.alert('&amp;amp; is an &amp; is normal text')">clickme</button>`

Comment: I should've specified this is a Spring project and the only option to configure Javascript is to change the project to a Javascript for which I created a copied version of the project and configured it to a JS project but with no luck, I get the same error.

Comment: Can you please fix the MY_API_KEY syntax error in the example above? The superfluous quotes mess up the syntax. Not sure if you actually have it like that in your eclipse code but if you have it like that you might wish to escape those quotes by `\"`

Comment: That was just to show where my API key is (I want to disclose it), the quotation mark should just be at the end of the URL, I've corrected it now.